# asp MVC adding a title inside a TextBoxFor()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am making a registration form for my website, and currently i have it like this 
[image]
and the code for that is :

```
@Html.Label("Firstname")
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Firstname, new {@required = "require", @style = "width:75%;", @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Firstname, null, new { @style = "color:red;" })
<br />
@Html.Label("Surname")
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Lastname, new { @required = "require", @style = "width:75%;", @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lastname, null, new { @style = "color:red;" })
<br /> . . .
```

What i am trying to do is to add the title for example "First Name" inside the textbox, when data is entered it would disappear, To look like this 
[image]

I have tried adding:

```
@name ="FirstName"
@label ="FirstName"
@title ="FirstName"
```

but all of those did nothing.

Comment: have you tried `@value = "FirstName"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are talking about [placeholder](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp). It's a HTML attribute, just add it to the custom `htmlAttributes` parameters, for exemple:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Firstname, new {@required = "require", @style = "width:75%;", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "First Name" })
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for the Html5 [placeholder attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp)

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Firstname, new {@required = "require", @style = "width:75%;", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "First Name" })
```

Answer (score 0):

This will add default value to your `TextBox`

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Firstname, new {@required = "require", 
                                                @style = "width:75%;", 
                                                @class = "form-control", 
                                                @value = "FirstName"})
```

Or if you want it to dissapear on entering the textbox

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Firstname, new {@required = "require", 
                                                @style = "width:75%;", 
                                                @class = "form-control", 
                                                placeholder = "FirstName"})
```